# CSS Sizing - Restricting child to parent dimensions

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to design a particular page, very similar to the code below. [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hzgac6dr/4/).

```css
#body {                   /* is actually absolute positioned  */
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
}

#parent {
  display: flex;
}

#child1 {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#child2 {
  flex: 0 0 150px;
  background-color: green;
}

#big {
  width: 900px;
  height: 490px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
  <div id="dummy">
    <!-- Other content here -->
    <div id="parent">
      <div id="child1">
        <div id="big"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="child2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What is the minimal CSS that I need to add to the elements on the page such that the **parent** div never exceeds the dimensions of the **body** div.

Comment: Did you try `width: 100%` or `max-width: 100%`?

Comment: When the parents content exceeds the body, what should happen?

Comment: Its the height that is the problem.. I have minimal CSS on the JS Fiddle link. I'll actually post some CSS here as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set height to **100vh** instead of **100%** because view-port unit work more efficient than percentage in case of height.
Rewrite **flex** code which will support following and its new version:
**IE 10, Safari 6, Firefox 20, Opera 12**.

```css
#body, #dummy, #parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

#body {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

#dummy {              
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

#parent {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;               
}

#child1 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;  
  background-color: yellow;
}

#child2 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
      -ms-flex: 0 0 150px;
          flex: 0 0 150px;
  background-color: green;
}

#big {
  width: 900px;
  height: 490px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
  <div id="dummy">
    <div id="parent">
      <div id="child1">
        <div id="big"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="child2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll try this out as well!

Answer (score 2):

For a child element to respect height, its parent must have a set `height`.

Here I added `height`/`max-height` (see comment in CSS)

```css
#body {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#dummy {                   /*  added #dummy  */
  display: flex;           /*  for IE 11  */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#parent {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;                  /*  for IE 11  */
  max-height: 100%;         /*  added property  */
  max-width: 100%;          /*  added property  */
}

#child1 {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;  
  background-color: yellow;
}

#child2 {
  flex: 0 0 150px;
  background-color: green;
}

#big {
  width: 900px;
  height: 490px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
  <div id="dummy">
    <div id="parent">
      <div id="child1">
        <div id="big"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="child2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, even though this is a solution to the problem - I can't really do this. I simplified the problem when I stated it - The **body** div essentially is an absolutely positioned div that has left, top, right and bottom set to 0. In essence - it has the effect of having a fixed width and height.

Comment: @AnandSainath To get a proper answer you need to give correct info. Anything more than that?

Comment: I can't use fixed width's anywhere - everything except the **big** div and **child2** div should be calculated on the fly.

Comment: @AnandSainath Updated my answer with the minimum required to achieve what you ask. Instead of right/bottom set to 0, I used width/height set to 100%, which gives same result.

Comment: @AnandSainath May I ask why you changed the accept? .. That answers code is redundant, apply properties that does nothing and state `100vh` is more efficient that `100%`, which it is not.